# Recursively apply functions on vector with purrr

Tags: r, purrr

Could somebody please tell me what the is the purrr version of this is:

```
fl <- list(sin, cos, cos, sqrt)
x <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 10)
Reduce(function(f, ...) f(...), fl, x, right = T)
```

(My trys with reduce and accumulate have not been successful.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(purrr)

lift(compose)(fl)(x)
#>  [1] 0.5143953 0.5528477 0.5880842 0.6202147 0.6493739 0.6757146 0.6994011
#>  [8] 0.7206037 0.7394947 0.7562439
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Or

```r
compose(!!! fl)(x)
```

Comment: Thanks. The quoting (`!!!`) of the second option does not work. Is it possible to fix that?

Comment: My purrr version is 0.3.0. Which is yours?